# Type Resolution in tsyringe

Tags: typescript, tsyringe

I recently started using `tsyringe` and I came across an issue with how dependencies are resolved. A reproducible scenario is explained below:

```js
class Client {
  exec(svcNum: number) {
    console.log("Executing ", svcNum);
  }
}

@injectable()
class Service1 {
  private readonly num = 1;
  constructor(private client: Client) {}
  serve() {
    this.client.exec(this.num);
  }
}

@injectable()
class Service2 {
  private readonly num = 2;
  constructor(private client: Client) {}
  serve() {
    this.client.exec(this.num);
  }
}
```

I have a `Client` class that is a dependency used by `Service1` and `Service2`. These can be easily resolved like this:

```js
const resolvedSvc1 = container.resolve(Service1);
const resolvedSvc2 = container.resolve(Service2);
```

Now what I need is something like this:

```js
container.register(Service1, { useClass: Service1 });
container.register(Service2, { useClass: Service2 });

const services = [ Service1, Service2 ]; // typeof Service1 | Service 2
services.forEach((svc) => {
  //container.register((svc as any).name, { useClass: svc });
  if (container.isRegistered((svc as any).name)) {
    console.log("Found registered service ", svc.name);
  }
  const resolved = container.resolve<typeof svc>(svc.name);
  (resolved as any).serve();
});
```

This does not work and TypeScript complains that `Error: Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "Service1"` when I run the code; also, the `console.log` prints nothing in the `if` block. I have found that `svc` has a union type `Service1 | Service2` and this probably causes the issue. Is there any way I can resolve the dependencies for services dynamically in this way at runtime? Narrowing `svc` to the appropriate type (i.e., either `Service1` or `Service2` will work I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering your services using the `class` but then trying to retrieve them by `name`:

```
container.register(Service1, { useClass: Service1 });
//                 ^^^^^^^^ ✅ registering the class here
```

```
const resolved = container.resolve<typeof svc>(svc.name);
//                ❌ trying to resolve by name ^^^^^^^^
```

There are two solutions for this:

```
// Option 1: register by class and resolve by class
container.register(Service1, { useClass: Service1 });
//                 ^^^^^^^^ ✅ register by class

const resolved = container.resolve<typeof svc>(svc);
//                         ✅ resolve by class ^^^
```

```
// Option 2: register using the class name and resolve by class or class name
container.register(Service1.name, { useClass: Service1 });
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ✅ register by class name

// can resolve by class
const resolved = container.resolve<typeof svc>(svc);
//                         ✅ resolve by class ^^^

// can resolve by class name
const resolved = container.resolve<typeof svc>(svc.name);
//                        ✅ resolve by class name ^^^^
```

Comment: Resolving by class name has worked as expected!